# RecyclerVIew equivalent in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Just like Android has `RecyclerView` consisting of different `models` and their corresponding different `views` having their own `behavior`. Is there any pre-built equivalent to this in `Ionic 2 (Angular 2)`?

Comment: did you get any answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

[Ngx-Sortable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-sortable), this is available since angular 4. Check the [demo page](https://manishjanky.github.io/ngx-sortable/)